# Outputting sound using multiple audio routes at the same time in an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-audio

I'm playing around with audio routes in AVAudioSession at the moment and I'm wondering whether it is possible to output sound to multiple audio routes at the same time i.e. a sound playing from the speaker and a different sound playing in the headphones? Ideally I'd like to be able to play separate sounds via a dock connector (using a 3.5mm jack adapter) and the headphone jack at the same time so if someone could tell me whether or not this is actually possible that would be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it was possible three years ago when you wrote this, but it is possible now to play one sound through the headphone jack and another through a USB audio interface connected to the dock connector. This [WWDC presentation](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_505__audio_session_and_multiroute_audio_in_ios.pdf) walks you through it and provides sample code.

I don't think it's possible to play separate sounds through the headphone jack and the speaker because the AVAudioSessionRouteDescription only shows one of these built-in output ports at a time. You'd have to add a second audio interface via USB, which adds a second output port to the AVAudioSessionRouteDescription. I'm testing with a [Roland Duo-Capture mk2](http://www.rolandus.com/products/details/1263/498) right now and it's working.